# docker-compose with Node and Mongo doesn't start both

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Symptoms:

1. If I run `docker-compose run mongo`, Mongo starts fine
2. If I run `docker-compose run iotmap` or `docker-compose up` only node starts, not the Mongo container plus

2a) `docker-compose ps` shows nothing and `docker ps` shows

```
e968900e41cc        6e70e14f1339        "/bin/sh -c 'npm sta…"   3 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        3000/tcp            priceless_hawking
```

2b) I get the following error

(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server_selection.js:309:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:537:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:481:7)
(node:25) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
ERROR: Aborting.

docker-compose.yml:

```
volumes:
  mongodata:
services:
  iotmap:
    container_name: iotmap
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
     - mongodata:/data/db
```

and Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --no-optional --no-shrinkwrap --no-package-lock
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
RUN npm start
```

and in app.js:

```
mongoose.connect( "mongodb://mongo:27017/iotmap", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true } );
```

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up`, do you see startup messages from MongoDB?  You have the application container marked `restart: always`; if you wait a minute or two (and let it restart), does it eventually come up?

Comment: no mongo is never mentioned. but your question made me think it's not the fact mongo is not starting, it's that node app didn't fully start. This time when I kiilled the node container I saw ```ERROR: Service 'iotmap' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm start' returned a non-zero code: 137``` which led me to check the ```Dockerfile```. I changed ```RUN npm start``` to ```CMD [ "npm", "start" ]``` and voila, everything starts like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Changing `RUN npm start` to `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` and everything starts like a charm!